# How can I save an image inside external storage and make it visible to gallery in Android 5.1?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, mediastore

I am writing a images downloading function in Android 5.1 (minSdkVersion 22，targetSdkVersion 29，compileSdkVersion 29). And I am not going to use any deprecated method or extra dependency.

I want to save the images in external storage, and make them visible to gallery (**i.e., after users having downloaded the images with my app, they can find those images in their gallery, without opening my app**).

In my project, I save images under `Context.getExternalFilesDir(null)` and the method will return the path like `/storage/sdcard/Android/data/com.example.myproject/files/`, but the question is: **the gallery doesn't display those downloaded images. Although in my app I can mannualy pass a content uri, which is created by **FileProvider**, to a new Intent and start the intent so users can view the image, but those images still invisible by users once they close my app. I want to keep those images in their gallery, even though my app is uninstalled**.

I have read several articles, they all told me I should use **Mediastore API**, but the api level of my app is only 22, and most of the Mediastore api only runs in Android 10.

My code example(inside an OKHttp callback):

```
@Override
                public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response)  {
                    File file=new File(task.getLocalPath());
                   // the path is something like: /storage/sdcard/Android/data/com.example.myproject/files/myimage.jpg
                    BufferedInputStream bfi;
                    RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile=null;
                    try {
                        randomAccessFile=new RandomAccessFile(file,"rw");
                        randomAccessFile.seek(task.getCurrent_size());
                        bfi=new BufferedInputStream(response.body().byteStream());
                        byte[] bbuf=new byte[1024];
                        int eachRead;

                        Log.d("downloading",task.getCurrent_size()+"/"+task.getTotalSize());
                        while ((eachRead=bfi.read(bbuf))!=-1){
                            if(task.getStatus()!=Entity_Task.STATUS_ON){
                                Log.d("download_control","do_cancel");
                                randomAccessFile.close();
                                bfi.close();
                                return;
                            }else{
                                randomAccessFile.write(bbuf,0,eachRead);
                                task.setCurrent_size(task.getCurrent_size()+eachRead);
                                //Log.d("downloading",task.getCurrent_size()+"/"+task.getTotalSize());
                            }
                        }
                        task.setStatus(Entity_Task.STATUS_COMPLETE);
                        Log.d("downloading","completed");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        task.setStatus(Entity_Task.STATUS_INVALID);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            response.close();
                            randomAccessFile.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }
```

And the xml of my provider:

```
<paths>
    <external-path name="sdcard" path="/"/>
</paths>
```

The code (inside a button click listener) which open the downloaded image:

```
            File file=new File(task.getLocalPath());
            ContentResolver contentResolver=v.getContext().getContentResolver();

            Uri uri=FileProvider.getUriForFile(v.getContext(),"com.example.myproject.myprovider",file);
            String mime = contentResolver.getType(uri);
            Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            target.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            target.setDataAndType(uri, mime);
            target.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            Intent intent=Intent.createChooser(target,"open file");
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

**All these codes work well, except that the gallery cannot see all the downloaded images**.

Comment: U should save images into the /storage/emulated/0/Pictures folder and then they will automatically show up in the gallery. You can also call Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) to get the Pictures folder.

Comment: @UrbanR Thanks.I would like to use Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory since different devices may have different paths of gallery directory. But I found  this method has been deprecated. Is there any alternative? The document says I should consider "Context#getExternalFilesDir(String), MediaStore, or Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.". But Context#getExternalFilesDir() and  ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT won't display the images in the gallery automatically , and MediaStore API only runs on Anroid 10. That's why I ask this question.

Comment: Since u have minimum API set to 22 i think you don't have any other option than using Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), since the newer methods won't be supprted in lower API levels. I looked further and i think you should save into DCIM folder so the call would look like Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM). MediaStore API runs on lower versions too, look through the documentation and you can see which methods were added before Android 10.